# Is it possible to add type information when declaring a nested data structure?

Tags: groovy

I want to declare a nested data structure that has nested collections/lists in it of a specific type. I'm wondering if there is a groovy feature that makes this kind of thing easy to declare just like you would a nested map or list.

For example I want a data structure that looks like this, where `items` can't be a regular map or list I want it to specifically be Object[]:

```
Object[] arrayOfObjects = [
  [
    aaa: "aaa",
    bbb: "aaa",
    ccc: "aaa",
  ],
  [
    sdfsdf: "aaa",
    ewerw: "aaa",
    ss: "aaa",
  ],
  [
    qweqwe: "aaa",
    sdfsdf: "aaa",
  ]
]

ArrayList myList = [
  [
    items: arrayOfObjects
  ],
  [
    items: arrayOfObjects // would be a different list of Object[] here
  ]
]
```

Is it possible to somehow do the same thing but like this, where you can cast a nested array as a specific type?

```
ArrayList myList = [
  [
    items: Object[] [
      [
        aaa: "aaa",
        bbb: "aaa",
        ccc: "aaa",
      ],
      [
        sdfsdf: "aaa",
        ewerw: "aaa",
        ss: "aaa",
      ],
      [
        qweqwe: "aaa",
        sdfsdf: "aaa",
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    items: Object[] [
      [
        oooo: "aaa",
        ddddd: "aaa",
        kljlkj: "aaa",
      ],
      [
        sdfsdf: "aaa",
        ssss: "aaa",
        ss: "aaa",
      ]
    ]
  ],
]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to cast a list literal to `Object[]`? Have you tried `[...] as Object[]`?

Comment: usually its not about declaring, but rather about reading the content of such collections